# is it possible to send curl another url as a param?

Tags: http, curl

I know I can do this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/myhandler' -F "myfile=@localfile"
```

so is it somehow possible to send a file that is on the web? Something like

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/myhandler' -F "myfile=@SOMEURL"
```

I cannot find the right way to apply that (I am guessing it is possible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the `curl` documentation -F can read from `stdin` using `-`. So if you pipe output from the url as follows, I think it should work:

`curl -vvv <url1> | curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8080/myhandler' -F "myfile=@-"`

Comment: I removed -vvv not sure what param is that, and it worked perfectly! thanks